# Sidekiq jobs are stuck in enqueued in production but not in development (Rails 7, Heroku deployment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I need help with my sidekiq and redis set up in my rails (7) app.

The problem is that all my Sidekiq jobs (emails) are being enqueued in production and not sending, but they work fine in development.

Here are my relevant files

sidekiq.rb

```
      require 'sidekiq/web'

      Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
        config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/1') }
      end

      Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
        config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/1') }
      end
```

sidekiq.yml

```
    development:
     :concurrency: 5

    production:
      verbose: false
      :concurrency: 5 
      :timeout: 8 

    :max_retries: 1

    :queues:
      - default
      - mailers
```

Procfile.dev

```
    web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
    worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

I have basically read all of the questions related to my problem and the lucid guidelines by Mike Perham. None of the answers work; to be fair, I am feeling my way in the dark. It's unclear what the issue is because I do not understand the processes thoroughly. I am new to Sidekiq. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have a way of checking whether your worker process is running? What do the logs from the worker say?

Comment: Hey, did you solve the issue? am facing same kind  of issue.